# $n$-dimensional polytopes with $(2n)$-vertices that are not really prisms

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes

Is there an $n\geqslant 3$ and a symmetric, convex polytope $V$ in $\mathbb R^n$ (symmetric means that if $x\in V$ then $-x\in V$ too) such that

- $V$ has $2n$-vertices and
- $V$ is not image of the cross-polytope
  $$ \{x\in\mathbb R^n\colon |x_1| +\ldots + |x_n| \leqslant 1\}?$$
  by a linear map?

Comment: The standard term for the figure whose points satisfy your inequality is ["cross-polytope"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope). In the case of $n=3$, the figure is an octahedron, which can be described as a triangular [anti-prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism), but not as a prism. ... Also, the type of symmetry you describe is specifically known as "central symmetry".

Comment: @JeanMarie are they really $n$-dimensional? Look like 3d objects to me. In dimesion $n$ I want them to have non-zero $n$-dimensional volume.

Comment: I hadn't paid attention to the fact that the $n$ in "$2n$" vertices was the same as the $n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Let the vertices be $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n,\;v_{n+1}=-v_1,\;v_{n+2}=-v_2,\;\cdots,\;v_{2n}=-v_n$.

Suppose the vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$ are linearly dependent. Then one of them is in the span of the other $n-1$ vectors. It follows that $v_{n+1},v_{n+2},\cdots,v_{2n}$ are also in the span of those $n-1$ vectors, so the whole polytope is in an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace. But you mentioned that the polytope must be full-dimensional. Hence, the vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$ must be linearly independent, and form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $M$ be the linear map defined by

$$(1,0,0,\cdots,0,0)\mapsto v_1$$
$$(0,1,0,\cdots,0,0)\mapsto v_2$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(0,0,0,\cdots,0,1)\mapsto v_n$$

or equivalently the matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}&&&\\v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_n\\&&&\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then $M$ maps the standard cross-polytope to your polytope.